# Distinguish GET from POST in PHP

Tags: php, cgi

I'm making a website, and have configured my web server to route any request for dynamic content to `index.php`.  On this site, some requests are `GET` others are `POST`.  How can I distinguish them?  Related questions are

- what is the value of the $_GET variable during a POST request?
- what is the value of the $_POST variable during a GET request?

Comment: A POST request has set $_POST values. A GET request has set $_GET values?

Comment: Does that mean the "wrong" superglobal doesn't exist?  Is empty?  Exists, but is equal to NULL?  And what happens if you do a POST on a URL like "http://some.site/page?arg1=foo&arg2=bar"?

Comment: @Nanne A POST request can also have `$_GET` values. A GET request will not have `$_POST` values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

> Which request method was used to access the page; i.e. 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT'.

Taken from the [$_SERVER docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 6):

> what is the value of the $_GET variable during a POST request?

Depends. Data can be present in both. The action for a `<form>` might be `example.php?action=testing`, which would result in `$_GET['action']` having the value of `testing`. All of the `$_POST` data would also be present.

> what is the value of the $_POST variable during a GET request?

An empty array.

Answer (score 4):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'
```